# Netezza Time datatype to Oracle

Tags: oracle, kettle, netezza

How to convert Netezza Time datatype to Oracle. We are migrating from Netezza to Oracle. Currently in netezza there is column which is having dataype time. How can I migrate the same to Oracle. I am using kettle as ETL tool for the same.

Answer (score 2):

I would go for the `TIMESTAMP` datatype in Oracle. If you have also a date column in Netezza you can combine it with the time column to store in Oracle a full `TIMESTAMP`.

Depending on your use case this solution can simplify or complicate your or the fron-end developers' life :)

**Edit:**

My preference would be to keep two separated columns, one with just the date and the second one for the time, but for the Oracle `TIMESTAMP` you will need to add the date:

**Neteza table**

```
Date_column | Time_column
2013-10-23  | 15:11
```

**Oracle table**

```
Date_column | Time_column (TIMESTAMP)
2013-10-23  | 2013-10-23 15:11
```

To keep the Date_column will allow the application using that column to work without changes, who is using the time_column will need to do some work (maybe just in terms of formatting)

Comment: There is no such type as 'datetime' in Oracle. You probably meant 'timestamp'.

Comment: Hi mucio...i have time data type in netezza...thus i m worried how to perform the migration....Even i tried timestamp but still unable to perform it

Comment: added some additional notes with a possible mapping of columns

Comment: Currently in netezza I have two column 1 for date and another for time. But my question is how to convert that time column in netezza to oracle db . which datatype should i use? any function need to be used in select query from netezza

Comment: if your problem is only how to query netezza,  you can use Date_column + Time_column to obtain a full time stamp with date + time. If you copy the time from Netezza to Oracle you will have values like 1/1/1970 + your original time

Comment: can you please provide query for the same...select query for netezza and insert query for oracle

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39841/discussion-between-user1251973-and-mucio)